# Mozilla Rendering issue

Tags: support

1. Today I have issue with proper rendering in Mozilla run on Win XP
2. There are two issues with

   - When I scroll code block

[image]

- Second I can't to reproduce by print_screen, because quickly flashing (black Color) toolbar when I moving mouse hover_over SO icons placed into URL Navigation bar.

Comment: No repro, works for me (tm). FF14 on XP (machine at work, sorry). AddOns? UserScripts? Wrongly configured color scheme (all text is selected)?

Comment: [Question in question for testing purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104833/java-event-queue-how-to-update-component-in-jframe).

Comment: @Waffelized Bobby no add_on, no scripts (restricted PC on work)

Comment: What browser version?

Comment: @Waffelized Bobby ...MF 14.0.1

Comment: @Waffelized Bobby I saw that a few times, couple weeks ago,

Comment: `no-repro` on FF 14.0.1 on Windows XP, tried cache unprimed as well.

Comment: Could be an issue with the hardware acceleration...in theory...go to the Settings, Advanced and disable the hardware acceleration. Restart Firefox and check again. If that doesn't work, hit the "Restart Firefox without addons" in the Help-Menu and try again.

Comment: PC restarted issue continue, Mozilla reseted to the default, maybe something wrong on my side, but I never saw this rendering issues out of SO sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caching issue`, all rendering issue gone away in the moment when I reseted `History` and together with `Advanced` -> `Network` -> `Cached Web Contents` (-: at 2175Mb :-), probably my issue